# Search Algorithm for Imperfect Matches in Series of Rows

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, search, search-engine

I'm working on demonstrating some principles of malware scanning (I don't know if this is a "traditional" method but I believe it will work to some extent, regardless, I'm trying to implement it).

At this stage I'm trying to map specific function calls (ie: networking calls) in a disassembled program and check my SQL database to see if there are any matches with known malware.

Here is what my "function calls" table looks looks like:

```
malwareID           address           function           order

    1               8048000            socket              1
    1               8048010            bind                2
    1               8048020            listen              3
    1               8048030            bind                4
    1               8048040            recv                5
```

At the moment I can only check for direct matches. I disassemble the target program, I retrieve all the network function calls and their addresses and I check for direct matches in the table (ie: `SELECT malwareID WHERE address = 'addr' AND function = 'func'`). This can detect some variants of a malware, but mostly doesn't work because it depends on the variant having the same function calls at the same address'.

What I would like to do instead is search for the function calls in the database by their 'order'. Let's say after disassembling and extrating function calls I end up with a list like this:

```
8041000     socket
8041010     bind
8041020     listen
8041030     bind
8041040     send
8041050     recv
```

While the addresses don't match the known variant stored in the database, the order of the calls and the "distance" between calls is the same/similar, except that a new `send` call was slipped in this new variant.

Since I've never done any software engineering or classes where you learn these kind of "searching" algorithms, I need pointed in the right direction.

**I'm looking for an algorithm that searches a database for a match to a series of rows, perhaps taking into account 'distances' between calls as well, and allows for some tolerance (ie: additional call inserted, missing one call, one call replaced by other).**

Are there any algorithms that do more or less this that I can read up on?

(Note: I'm working with Python and sqlite, but I welcome any pseudo-codish ideas on how to do this)

Comment: One part of what you're looking for would be classified as [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). It's a very broad subject in itself, even without the distance hints

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you, I've checked out the wiki page and it does look like what I'm looking for. Apparently there are Python modules that implement this. Those libraries seem to work mostly with strings though, I was thinking of perhaps converting each function call to a certain character (ie: socket = 'a', bind='b' etc). I could then compare two strings using for example **difflib**. Does this sound like a reasonable way to do it?

Comment: Well the problem with that approach is that you need to compare the string with all the samples in your database. There are ways to find a match in sublinear time, but that's way more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you should consider storing pairs of function calls and storing the address distance between those calls.  Something like :

```
malwareID       functionA  distance functionB       order

1               socket    10        bind            1
1               bind      10        listen          2
1               listen    10        bind            3
1               bind      10        recv            4
```

This way you can do simple SQL query where can do a count(*) to check if there is enough matches to raise a malware security issue.

Comment: +1! Wish I'd thought about it myself, or that you had answered two weeks ago! I already handed in my project :) Combining this with what Niklas B. suggested in comment should work pretty good, will try it out.